# PutHiveQL NiFi Processor extremely slow - misconfiguration?

Tags: sql, hive, apache-nifi

I am currently setting up a simple NiFi flow that reads from a RDBMS source and writes to a Hive sink.  The flow works as expected until the PuHiveSql processor, which is running extremely slow.  It inserts one record every minute approximately.
Currently is setup as a standalone instance running on one node.

[image]

The logs showing the insert every 1 minute approx:

(`INSERT INTO customer (id, name, address) VALUES (x, x, x)`)
[image]

Any ideas about why this may be?  Improvements to try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting **one record at a time** into Hive will result extreme slowness.

As your doing **regular insert** into hive table:

**`Change your flow:`**

```
QueryDatabaseTable
PutHDFS
```

Then create [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable) `avro` table on top of **HDFS directory** where you have stored the data.

**(or)**

```
QueryDatabaseTable
ConvertAvroToORC //incase if you need to store data in orc format
PutHDFS
```

Then create Hive `orc` table on top of **HDFS directory** where you have stored the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you poshing one record at time? if so may use the merge record process to create batches before pushing into HiveQL,

It is recommended to batch into 100 records :
See here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hive-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveQL/

> Batch Size | 100 | The preferred number of FlowFiles to put to the database in a single transaction

Use the MergeRecord process and set the number of records or/and timeout, it should speed-up considerably

Comment: @Issilva Yes I set the batch to one at a time.  When I set it to 100 or 50 even it just takes even longer and I do not see any insertions at all.  I have set it to 50 now but it is similarly slow. Can you explain how MergeRecord processor would help in this case?

Comment: The mergeRecords has two properties to trigger a succes, 1 is the number of records and the other is a time. So this must be fine-tuned based on how much data you have or how fast you want it. Say 100 records or 1seconds so if after 1seconds you didn't get 100 records it will still go forward.